# Static route and forward traffic between two interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, routing, forwarding

I have two linux servers configured as following:

1. eth0 192.168.1.200
   ip route add 172.22.0.3 via 192.168.1.172
2. eno0 192.168.1.172
   eno1 172.22.0.3
   net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.200/24 -j MASQUERADE

I can't ping 172.22.0.3 from server 1. I see the request on server 2 with tcpdump, but no reply back to server 1

Comment: are 192.168.1.200 and 192.168.1.172 in the same subnet? `192.168.1.200/24` in your IP tables looks off.

Comment: 192.168.1.X are in the same subnet